How to catch the SQL Server network-related errors in C# correctly?
I want to catch all network-related exceptions from SQL Server (connection lost, timeout, etc.) and show a warning dialog to the end user when SQL Server instance suddenly goes down.
The SqlException contains the list of errors which is supposed to show the exact error to me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number?view=netframework-4.8.1
However, based on my tests, whenever I stop the SQL Server service, the only property in this collection contains SqlError.Number property set to "-1".
if (ex is SqlException sqlException)
{
    int number = ex.Number; // -1
}

The error message says

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

So, my questions are

Is it safe to assume that if SqlError collection contains only a record with a number "-1", then it's a network-related issue?
If not, how can I get this specific "provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" information from the SqlException object?
If I try to get that number "26" by parsing the error message, that will be error-prone, right? I assume these error messages can be localized to other languages based on the system settings.
Is there any documentation of all possible issues related to losing the connection to the SQL Server instance and a proper recommendation how to catch it in C#?

I tried to find a documentation about those issues, but couldn't find any helpful link about it.



I get ex.Number as 2 not -1

Now that System.Data.SqlClient is officially deprecated are you sure that you want to develop new software using it? Have you started testing behaviours against Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which will most likely have several differences considering its already different feature sets? Its source is also available on Github which helps to make its behaviours traceable and explainable.

Sounds like a waste of time, if your instance goes down this often, you have bigger problems than nice error messages. Why not just catch and display something generic and sniff out the message if you really want to have something specific

@AlwaysLearning I've upgraded to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. I still get the same behavior coming from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException class. The Number property is set to "-1".

@siggemannen That's what I am trying to solve. I want to pause everything when SQL Server instance goes off. But for that, I need to catch that first.

@Charlieface Strange, I'm clearly getting "-1". I just open SQL Server Configuration Manager and stop the instance from there to reproduce it.

Can you instead of explaining your "solution", explain the problem you want to solve? What do you mean by pause

@siggemannen My program is doing a long-running job (can take days). I want to pause the job and notify users when suddenly their SQL Server instance goes off after a day or so. The idea is to pause the job and provide them a nice dialog asking them to fix their SQL Server issues and click on the "Resume" button.

Both System.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient return ex.Number as 2 for me. Also ex.Errors[0].Number is also 2.

@Charlieface Edited the post and included a screenshot of the SqlException that I'm reproducing on my end. Both ex.Number and ex.Errors[0].Number are "-1" in my end. I don't know if the SQL Server version difference can be the reason.

Have you checked the Errors collection?

Which exact build of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?

Ok, so what's the difference between just catching the error and telling them: "something is wrong, check that server is available and resume"

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes, as I mentioned in my previous comment it's the same. I've attached another screenshot with the "Errors" collection node expanded.

@Charlieface Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.2.2 with .NET Framework 4.8 and SQL Server 2022.

@siggemannen How to catch the error? That IS my question. I can't catch SqlException in general and pause the job since it can be minor issue specific to the current operation. I need a way to understand when SQL Server goes off (preferrably by the exception code and not by parsing the error message text).

The Class in that screenshot is 20 and as the docs explain, the server would close the connection anyway. The class is equivalent to the error severity

Even if server goes away or a rabbit eats it or you get a PK violation, you don't know because your current operation will die. You still need to start over?

@PanagiotisKanavos Do you think it will be safe enough if I will pause the job whenever the Class property of the SqlException will be >=20. What are the other cases of such exceptions?

There are so many other non-recoverable exceptions, it does seem a bit weird to only catch one particular type. I have written a lot of code using SqlClient and have never done this, I just catch all exceptions and bail out using a finally and using and transactions.

@Charlieface I understand. But for my specific case I really need to separate between "non-recoverable" exceptions and regular SQL statement exceptions (e.g. duplicate key). I don't want my program keep running when the server is OFF (let's say I can keep checking if the server is OFF for about 10 minutes and if it does not recover, pause the job). On the other hand, if it's a simple duplicate key exception, I sometimes can ignore/handle it and move on. If there is a way to catch all "non-recoverable" exceptions, I would be happy to re-use that.

I don't know, a duplicate key sounds non-recoverable to me. All depends on your viewpoint. Why don't you just catch and handle the ones you are sure about, and bail out on everything else?

@Charlieface There are tons of minor SQL exceptions. I don't want to pause the overnight job for something minor. Basically, my initial idea was to pause only when SQL Server goes offline. But apparently, it's not that easy to determine....

Ok, but what's the worst that will happen if you don't pause your job? Regardless of server status. I have written a LOT of code over the years ,and the only time i needed to sniff out exceptions is when i wanted to avoid logging excessive errors

@siggemannen I guess every case the specific. In my case, not pausing would lead to hours of meaningless loop and incorrect/missing DB records. All in all, users will have to do the same multi-day job again to have whatever they need.

I'm sorry but i don't believe you, let's say you get a "non"-critical error, then you continue and the server died just before you continued. It will still lead to errors or whatever. My point is, you can never know when the server has died until you try something. I'm pretty sure you're on the wrong track but good luck, i'm out

@siggemannen Let's say I have 5 billion items I have to loop through. "Non"-critical errors that could happen from time to time can lead to 100 of those items to not get processed successfully. That is OK for me and my clients, they can retry those 100 things later (or I can debug their specific issues to see what was the problem). However, "no connection" is an error that would make ALL items after that point to get issues. Time is money. Re-doing billions of things again is not practical. Therefore, I want to distinguish between those. In any case, thanks for trying to help :)

Ok, you mean you have some items, you first do some calculations without the database and you don't wanna waste them if the db is down? Ok, but you can then implement some logic like: After 5000 failed rows in a row, you cancel the big processing and then display some message. Or you just have a retry connection check which pauses the job while the connection is down, while displaying some message or whatever. This way, you can immediately go bac kto processing when the connection is up again
